# Web API 2 Odata V4 PATCH return 404

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2, odata-v4

I have this controller :

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData;

public class InvRecipientAutoInvoiceController : ODataController
    {
        // GET: odata/InvRecipientAutoInvoice
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Inv_RecipientAutoInvoice> GetInvRecipientAutoInvoice()
        {
            return db.Inv_RecipientAutoInvoice.Where(a=>a.CompanyNumber == CompanyNumber);
        }

    [AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]   
    public IHttpActionResult Patch([FromODataUri] int RecipientNumber , [FromODataUri] int RecipientType, Delta<Inv_RecipientAutoInvoice> patch)
        {
            // XXXX Some Update Code
        }
    }
```

The GET works and I get result and can even sort them.
but when I do a PATCH request,  I get 404 error ,
the PATCH request :

Request URL: http://localhost:61240/odata/InvRecipientAutoInvoice(RecipientNumber%3D443%2CRecipientType%3D400)

```
   Request Method: PATCH
```

- Response Body :

> {   "error":{
>       "code":"","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:61240/odata/InvRecipientAutoInvoice(RecipientNumber=443,RecipientType=400)'.","innererror":{
>         "message":"No action was found on the controller 'InvRecipientAutoInvoice' that matches the
>   request.","type":"","stacktrace":""
>       }   } }

- Request body  :

> ```
> {"InvoiceLine1Description":"32132"}
> ```

I am using it in an  ASP.net web project (not MVC),

the register is :

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
routeName: "ODataRoute",
routePrefix: "odata",
model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@yaniv

It seems that you want to use the built-in routing conventions to patch the entity with **composite keys**. However, [the built-in routing conventions](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-02-built-in-routing-conventions) doesn't support the composite keys.

You can either custom your own routing conventions ( see [here](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-04-custom-routing-convention) ) or just use the [attribute routing](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-03-attrribute-routing).

Attribute routing is simple and easy to use. You only need to put an [ODataRouteAttribute](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Routing/ODataRouteAttribute.cs) on your **Patch** action, then it should work.

```
[AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
[ODateRoute("InvRecipientAutoInvoice(RecipientNumber={RecipientNumber},RecipientType={RecipientType})"]
public IHttpActionResult Patch([FromODataUri] int RecipientNumber , [FromODataUri] int RecipientType, Delta<Inv_RecipientAutoInvoice> patch)
{
     // XXXX Some Update Code
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you make the call, what's the requested contenttype? Is it application/json-patch+json ? ( instead of application/json )